# Input field with immutable text at end

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, input

[Input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UaP8.png)

I want an input field with a "%" at the back of the input always. This is my react component so far:

```
              <StyledBaseInput
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                value={inputAmount}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<StyledBaseInput
   type="text"
   className="form-control"
   value={inputAmount+'%'}
   onChange={handleInputChange}
/>
var handleInputChange = (e) => {
  setInputAmount(e.target.value.slice(0, -1))
}
```

If you use class component, try like this

```js
<StyledBaseInput
  type="text"
  className="form-control"
  value={inputAmount + '%'}
  onChange={handleInputChange}
/>

var handleInputChange = (e) => {
  setState({inputAmount: e.target.value.slice(0, -1)})
}
```

Comment: hi I already tried this but the cursor allows me to go to the right of the percentage, how do i prevent that?

Answer (score -1):

```js
 <div class="size-input-wrapper">
    <label for="inputValidation">Enter size:</label>
    <input type="text" id="inputValidation" placeholder="size"/>
    <span class="pxSpan">px</span>
 </div>
```

```css
.size-input-wrapper {
    max-width: 208px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
#inputValidation {
    padding-right: 35px;
}
.pxSpan {
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    right: 10px;
}
```